# What is this function notation

Tags: functions, notation

I am studying functions and equations and in my textbook I have this definition:

A function $f:A\to B$ is invertible if there is a function $g:B\to A$ such that $f\circ g=1_B$ and $g\circ f=1_A$.

What are $1_B$ and $1_A$? I have never seen this notation.

Thanks.

Comment: If $S$ is a set then $\mathbb 1_S$ is the identity function from $S\to S$.

Comment: E.g. $1_B$ is the function $B\to B$ prescribed by $b\mapsto b$. Such functions are called identities.

Comment: So $1_A=f:A\rightarrow A$ st $f(x)=x$ ?

Comment: @lulu: Isn't it called an indicator function, not an identity function?

Comment: @Joe  An indicator function, usually defined on a subset $S\subset T$ , is $1$ on $S$ and $0$ on $T-S$.    The same notation may sometimes be used for that, but the context the OP provides makes it clear that we are speaking of the identity function.

Comment: @lulu: Oh, I see. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Neox: Yes, that is correct. Here is a translation of your definition into more familiar words: a function $f:A\to B$ is invertible if there is a function $g:B\to A$ such that $f(g(x))=x$ for all $x\in B$ and $g(f(x))=x$ for all $x\in A$. This function $g$ is conventionally written as $f^{-1}.$

Comment: By the way, you can use ``\to`` for $\to$, which is easier to type than ``\rightarrow``.

Comment: @Joe Thanks for advice.

Comment: @Neox: No problem! I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, $1_A$ means the identity function $\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}\id:A\to A$ such that $\id(x)=x$. I have also seen the notation $1_{A}$ to refer to an indicator function: that is, a function $f$ defined on a subset $A$ of $X$ such that
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
1 &\text{if $x\in A$,} \\
0 &\text{if $x\in X\setminus A$,}
\end{cases}
$$
so it is important to be aware of different conventions.

Here is a translation of your definition into more familiar words: a function $f:A\to B$ (where $B$ is the range of $f$) is invertible if there is a function $g:B\to A$ such that $f(g(x))=x$ for all $x\in B$ and $g(f(x))=x$ for all $x\in A$. We typically write $f^{-1}$ for $g$.